# Python urlib2 TLSv1

Tags: python

Im currently using urlib to pull some data via a RESTful API. Is there a simple way to instruct it to use wither SSLv3 or TLSv1 ..

```
   try:
        request = urllib2.Request(api_query)
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % self.userpass)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        response = f.read()
        f.close()
        return response
    except Exception, e:
        print "error :",e
```

Thanks,